# How do you structure a rails model where two attributes need to share the same association with another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, model-associations

I'm working on a Rails app that is a compendium of quotes that artists have said about other artists, and I'm having trouble figuring out how the relationships in my data model should work.

Take this quote as an example. Here is something David Bowie said about Lou Reed:

> "He was a master"

My attributes for a Quote model in this example would be something like this:

- Excerpt  => "He was a Master"
- Speaker  => "David Bowie"
- Subject  => "Lou Reed"

But what if Lou Reed said something about David Bowie, such as this:

- Excerpt => "He was my best friend in the 70s"
- Speaker => "Lou Reed"
- Subject => "David Bowie"

An artist could be both a speaker or a subject of a Quote, but never of the same quote. I'd also like users to be able to create new Artists and then have those appear as options to associate with a quote (via a dropdown or search, etc.) when they are creating a Quote.

It seems that I can't structure it so that the Quote has many Artists through Speakers, because it could also have many Artists through Subjects.

Is this the idiomatic Rails way to structure this:

```
Quote
has_one :speaker
has_one :subject

Speaker
has_many :artists
belongs_to_many :quotes

Subject
has_many :artists
belongs_to_many :quotes

Artist
belongs_to_many :speakers
belongs_to_many :subjects
```

Comment: is the author distinction of `subject` important?  If not, a Quote `
has_and_belongs_to_many :authors`, could work I think

Comment: It only matters to the Quote model. All Artists (aka authors) are the same, but on some quotes they will be the artist being spoken about, and on others an Artist will be the one doing the Speaker (so they can be the subject of the quote and the speaker of the quote, but never on the same quote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want Quote to look something like:

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :speaker, class_name: "Artist"
  belongs_to :subject, class_name: "Artist"
  belongs_to :user

  validates :speaker, uniqueness: {scope: :subject}
  validates :subject, uniqueness: {scope: :speaker}

  ...

end
```

This assumes:

- A User (probably current_user or something like that) is creating the quote and that the quote belongs to that user.
- An Artist is a distinct notion from User. That is, an Artist is not necessarily a User (a Quote may have David Bowie as a subject, but David Bowie may not be a User of your system (especially given that he has passed away as has Lou Reed)).

This way, both `speaker` and `subject` are specified as being of the class `Artist`.

The uniqueness validations ensure that a `speaker` is never a `subject` and visa-versa. (You may need to twiddle with the `validates` statement as I did not test.)

In your `Artist` model, you probably want to do something like:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :spoken_quotes, class_name: "Quote", foreign_key: :speaker_id
  has_many :referencing_quotes, class_name: "Quote", foreign_key: :subject_id

  ...

end
```

That way, you could do something like:

```
Artist.find_by(name: 'David Bowie').spoken_quotes
```

And get all the `Quotes` for which David Bowie is the `speaker`.

And, in your `User` model, you probably want something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :quotes

  ...

end
```

So that you can do something like:

```
current_user.quotes
```

And get all the quotes the `current_user` has created.

Comment: Yes those assumptions are correct. That makes sense and is much simpler than I was imagining. Why would Quote not own Artist instead of how you have it structured? In my mind the Quote is the central data model and the artist is simply an attribute that needs to also be available to be created by the User. (A User is never an Artist.) It seems to me that the Quote has_many :artists and Artist belongs_to_many :quotes where Speaker and Subject inherit from Artist?

Comment: am I wrong that your approach is backwards? I'm thinking the speaker / subject should belong to Quote. Is this wrong?

Comment: It's all about how Rails handles cardinality and in this case, specifically, how it handles one-to-many. A `Quote` can be spoken by only one `Artist` - so `Quote` gets the `belongs_to` part of the one-to-many relationship (and contains the `speaker_id` foreign key to `Artist`). An `Artist` can speak many `Quotes`, so it gets the `has_many` part of the one-to-many relationship. Check out the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more detail.

Comment: Saying that the speaker/subject should belong to Quote suggests that an Artist can have only one Quote. I do not believe that is what you intend.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. Again, feel free to accept (nice for me and nice for future searchers/readers).

Comment: jvillian I'm trying this but stumped on how to create the association and display it in my forms / views. Keep getting an active record association mismatch error. How do I use this in a dropdown?

Comment: Hey, Lee. Late over there. Sorry to hear you're still having problems. It's hard to opine without seeing models, associations, and errors (minimally). You could add to your current question. Or, create a new question. Or, perhaps a chat, if you like.

Comment: jvillian - appreciate all your help. I created a new question to post the models, controller, associations, form, and db schema here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334107/activerecordassociationtypemismatch-in-controllercreate-on-dropdown-select-fo - I'm still a ruby nuby so trying to wrap my head around associations and still stumped on this one.

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have the following schema:

```
user - id
quote - author_id, subject_id
```

you can make the relations like so, making use of the options available to these association methods:

```
# User
has_many :sent_quotes, class_name: "Quote", foreign_key: :author_id
has_many :received_quotes, class_name: "Quote", foreign_key: :subject_id
has_many :quote_receivers, through: :sent_quotes, source: :subject
has_many :quote_senders, through: :received_quotes, source: :authors

# Quote
belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :subject, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: The User is not the Artist in this case. Speaker and Subject (via the Artist model) is just metadata on the Quote model. The User can create Artists or Quotes.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly Then you can take my example and change User to Artist. There's a saying that one the hardest things about programming is naming variables