# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Controller#create on dropdown select for a Rails self join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, self-join

I'm getting an ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error on my self join in Rails 5 that I can't figure out how to fix.

It's a simple rails app where a user can share a quote by an Artist (such as David Bowie) about another Artist (such as Lou Reed). So, a quote might look like this:

*Quote*
Topic: David Bowie
Content: "He was a master."
Speaker: Lou Reed

I have a Quote model and an Artist model and the Topics and Speakers are defined as self joins on the Artist model.

Here are the models:

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope -> { order(name: :asc) }

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :spoken_quotes, class_name: "Quote", foreign_key: :speaker_id
  has_many :topic_quotes,  class_name: "Quote", foreign_key: :topic_id

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name,    presence: true, length: { maximum: 60 },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :speaker, class_name: "Artist"
  belongs_to :topic,   class_name: "Artist"

  validates :speaker, uniqueness: {scope: :topic}
  validates :topic,   uniqueness: {scope: :speaker}

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1200 }
  validates :source,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 60 }

end
```

Here's the database schema:

```
create_table "artists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_artists_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_artists_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "quotes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "artist_id"
    t.text "content"
    t.string "source"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["artist_id", "created_at"], name: "index_quotes_on_artist_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["artist_id"], name: "index_quotes_on_artist_id"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_quotes_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_quotes_on_user_id"
  end
```

Here's the relevant code from my Quotes Controller:

```
  def create
    @quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params)
    if @quote.save
      flash[:success] = "Quote created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def quote_params
      params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :source, :topic, :artist_id)
  end
```

And the dropdown for the Topic of a Quote (which is an Artist) on the new Quote form:

```
<%= f.collection_select :topic, Artist.all, :id, :name %>
```

The dropdown looks fine and appears to be creating the association correctly, but when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
Artist(#70317289606580) expected, got "15" which is an instance of String(#70317259521760)
```

And the error message highlights the first line in the create action:
    @quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params)

Am I defining my params wrong? What is wrong about my create action to cause this error. I can't seem to figure it out after researching it a bunch and trying various solutions.

Comment: I had to change my `f.select :related_model` to `f.select :related_model_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lee -

Your `Quote` and `Artist` models look OK. Your schema, however, is wrong. It should look like:

```
create_table "artists", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "quotes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "speaker_id"
  t.integer  "topic_id"
  t.text     "content"
  t.string   "source"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Note `speaker_id` and `topic_id` instead of `artist_id`.

I'd need to see your stack trace to see what might be wrong with how you have other things set up.

BTW, have you fixed your params whitelist? This is wrong:

```
def quote_params
  params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :source, :topic, :artist_id)
end
```

Since your params look like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7xXgP3T1ZyxVhnr9TtBxeuYSRLBiuX01JSkQ4m4rN9pBS1W0iW6TJtsS7KyvunpCIZFiFltmdEwZGIYqsnxbyw==", "quote"=>{"topic_id"=>"2", "speaker_id"=>"1", "content"=>"asdfadsf", "source"=>"http://fuzz.com"}, "commit"=>"Post"}
```

It should be:

```
def quote_params
  params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :source, :topic_id, :speaker_id)
end
```

As a shot in the dark, try changing:

```
validates :speaker, uniqueness: {scope: :topic}
validates :topic,   uniqueness: {scope: :speaker}
```

To:

```
validates :speaker_id, uniqueness: {scope: :topic_id}
validates :topic_id,   uniqueness: {scope: :speaker_id}
```

I'll update with explanation if that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm figuring this out, but getting a new error now. Stack trace -https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/0b692d85076a7659418d7dc2915d0207

Comment: I commented on the gist.

Comment: updated gist. sorry I copied the Full Trace from the error message

Comment: also, params are now `params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :source, :topic_id, :speaker_id, :artist_id)` but it seems like `artist_id` should not be needed now?

Comment: schema looks like this - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/0067396a8db088b326d14c0f55fc95ac

Comment: When I set my params exactly how you have listed above like this `params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :source, :topic_id, :artist_id)` I get a form error saying that "speaker must exist" but the form seems to work. When I add `:speaker_id` to the params then I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.topics`

Comment: Params are `params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :source, :topic_id, :speaker_id)`. Forms are `<%= f.collection_select :topic_id, Artist.all, :id, :name %>` and `<%= f.collection_select :speaker_id, Artist.all, :id, :name %>` and keep getting the `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid SQLite3::SQLException: no such table:` error

Comment: Check out last update - I'm thinking your scoped validates are the problem.

Comment: jvillian really appreciate your help so much. I got this working by removing `foreign_key: true` from my quotes migration. Previously I had `t.references :speaker, foreign_key: true` and `t.references :topic, foreign_key: true`. By removing  foreign_key: true it worked just fine. I didn't have to change the validations to get the form to submit, but I did have to change the validations to `scope: :topic_id` and `scope: :speaker_id` for them to actually validate the form as expected. I learned a lot in this process and could not have gotten there without your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your select with:

```
<%= f.collection_select :topic_id, Artist.all, :id, :name %>
```

and permit `topic_id` with on your controller:

```
params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :source, :topic_id, :artist_id)
```

You can pass on object as an argument for belongs_to association in `rails c`:

```
Quote.new(topic: Artist.first)
```

and Rails'll do rest, but you can't pass an object via http request, but instead you should pass an object's id.

**Updated**

I'm confused about how do you want to bind Quote with speaker(Artist) and topic(Artist) having the `artist_id` column on `quotes` table only? It seems you should have different columns to store these connections. And then you'll be able to use the name of the column for select's name.

Comment: Thanks, actually tried this first after researching the problem and keep getting this error in the browser `undefined method `topic_id' for #<Quote:0x00007fe806aaece0> Did you mean?  topic` -- In the console I'm getting `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `topic_id`` It seems like I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: Re: updated - it was based on what jvillian recommend here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214369/how-do-you-structure-a-rails-model-where-two-attributes-need-to-share-the-same-a/48214773?noredirect=1#comment83412647_48214773 - I was under the impression the Quote could belong to Artist and Artist has many quotes then I could use a self join in the models to make the connection, sort of like the example given in rails guides here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins. But this very well could be the problem & I'm not understanding the self join correctly.

Comment: I guess you got it wrong. In the example there are some employees. But one employee can be manager for another, but they are both employee anyway. To implement the connection between them you can use self join. But in you case you want to connect different models, Quote and Artist. And you want to have two links, so you should have a column for each of them.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so I should add columns on my Artist table, called speaker_id & topic_id. Am I understanding that right now?

Comment: You have to add speaker_id and topic_id to your quotes table so a quote will know who said it and about whom. Then you'll be able to use `belongs_to :topic, class_name: 'Artist'` and `belongs_to :speaker, class_name: 'Artist'` on your Quote model

Comment: actually, update on this, the validations only work the first time you create a quote. The second time you create a quote using the same artists, it says they must be unique. The first time you create a quote with 2 artists the validations work, but then the second time you attempt to use those artists you get `Speaker has already been taken` and `Topic has already been taken`. So this isn't the intended behavior of the validations. Gonna have to look into that.